# jquery callback function

Tags: jquery, callback, get

instead of writing code in the standard way:

```
$.get('test.xml',function(){
    //manipulate the code here
})
```

I wanted to write the code this way to make things easier:

```
$.get('test.xml',callback(data));

function callback(data){
    //manipulate with the data below...
}
```

but error show "data is undefined", how can i fix this?

Comment: thanks for all the answers and comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write

```
$.get('test.xml',callback);
```

---

When you write

```
$.get('test.xml',callback(data));
```

then `callback` gets executed **immediately** (you call the function).

---

Or if `data` is not supposed to be the data returned from the Ajax call, but some parameter you want to pass to the function, you have two possibilities:

1. Make `callback` return a function.
2. Wrap the `callback` call in an anonymous function:

   ```
   $.get('test.xml',function(){callback(data);});
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the data out. it is a parameter automatically given to the callback function:

```
$.get('test.xml',callback);

function callback(data){
    //manipulate with the data below...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.get('test.xml',function(){callback(data)});
```

JS can't handle variables for callback-functions your way